# Simulate a POST request

Tags: jquery, post, node.js, express

I am developing a node.js app using express. I'm listening on port 3000 of localhost for POST requests. The only way I know how to simulate a POST request is using `jQuery.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:3000',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {hello: 1},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I get a the error message:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."

What am I doing stupidly? Is there a better approach I should consider?

Comment: You can write a unit test in node using [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

Comment: @Raynos: Thanks. That's really helpful.

Comment: I have some [http unit tests](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/tree/master/test/http). They might be readable / point you in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use unix command `curl` to simulate the requests. With it you get horde of options.

In your case it would be `curl http://localhost:3000 -d "{hello:1}" -X POST`

Answer (score 2):

Use `http://localhost:3000` for the url... otherwise it gets used as a directory or file